# How do I stop javascript from autoloading when on a pagination page?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Basically, I have javascript refreshing a table of orders every 2 seconds. It queries a route called 'autoload' which triggers a method called autoloadOrders in the OrdersController. The controller simply returns a view of a partial blade file with the loop for the table in it (with necessary variables being passed).

My question is, the refreshing works fine and the table auto-updates. But for pagination, when I click to the next page, it auto-reverts back to the first page data every 2 seconds. How can I stop that from happening once I'm going through the pagination?

welcome.blade.php

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $('#autoload').load('{{ route('autoload') }}');
                }, 2000);
            });
        </script>
    <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
            <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
        </div>

        <h2>View Orders</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive" id="autoload">
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>phone</th>
                    <th>address</th>
                    <th>order</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>delivered</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($orders as $order)

                <tr>
                    @if ($order->delivered == false)
                    <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$order->phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{$order->address}}</td>
                    <td>{!! nl2br($order->products) !!}</td>
                    <td>${{$order->price}}</td>
                        @if ($order->pickup == true)
                            <td><a href="/admin/orders/pickup/{{$order->id}}">Pickup</a></td>
                        @else
                            <td><a href="/admin/orders/deliver/{{$order->id}}">No</a></td>
                            @endif

                     @endif
                </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        {{$orders->links()}}
```

autoload.blade.php

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="autoload">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>phone</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>order</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>delivered</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($orders as $order)

            <tr>
                @if ($order->delivered == false)
                    <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$order->phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{$order->address}}</td>
                    <td>{!! nl2br($order->products) !!}</td>
                    <td>${{$order->price}}</td>
                    @if ($order->pickup == true)
                        <td><a href="/admin/orders/pickup/{{$order->id}}">Pickup</a></td>
                    @else
                        <td><a href="/admin/orders/deliver/{{$order->id}}">No</a></td>
                    @endif

                @endif
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

OrdersController

```
public function autoloadOrders(Orders $orders)
    {
        return view('admin.partials.autoload')->with(['orders' => $orders->getUndeliveredOrders()]);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('autoload', 'OrdersController@autoloadOrders')->name('autoload');
```

Comment: You need to pass current selected page via js to the route auto load.  so that even with refresh you get the data of the current selected page

or you can try `var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(fname, 10000);
/* later */
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);`

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of how to use this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                if (!url) url = window.location.href;
                name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                if (!results) return null;
                if (!results[2]) return '';
                return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {


                var check = getParameterByName('page');
                if ((check === '1') || (check === null)) {
                    var autoLoad = setInterval(function() {
                        $('#autoload').load('{{ route('autoload') }}');
                    }, 2000);
                } else {clearInterval(autoLoad);}

            });
```